# What does this sentence mean by "challenging modern media outlets"?

Tags: meaning

> The growth, exponential inﬂuence and scope of participation in social media, challenging modern media outlets, is rivalling that of nation states.

What does "challenging modern media outlets" refer to?

Comment: When you ask about what a sentence means, you should do two things: (1) Cite where you got it from, to provide more context (a link to the full news article, or the entire paragraph from a novel, will usually suffice); (2) Explain where the source of your confusion lies. For example, do you not know what a "media outlet" is? Do you know what a "media outlet" is, but you're not sure what makes a media outlet "modern"? Do you not understand how modern media outlets can be "challenged" by social media? In short, we need a little more context, and we need a little more direction.

Comment: In this case, there might be enough information here for members of ELL to attempt to answer this. We'll see if this question garners close votes or answers, but, if people start voting to close it, at least you'll know how to fix it, as well as how to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The way that is worded sounds to me as if social media is competing with modern media outlets.  If that is the case, it could be reworded thusly:

> The growth, exponential inﬂuence and scope of participation in social media is challenging modern media outlets and rivalling that of nation states.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean one of two things. I think the first is more like:

> Social media are challenging, but are rivaling nations in power.

or

> Social media are posing challenges for other modern media, such as
>   television.

with more context it might be easier to decide.